# Differences between 摔，落 and 掉

Tags: word-choice, mandarin

The 3 words all have a meaning of fall but what are the differences between the 3 of them?

Comment: are there any dictionaries supplying "fall" as only possible translation? subject amply covered in online dictionaries (note esp. sample phrases): bkrs, iciba. LINE dictionary, etc.  http://www.iciba.com/fall also google "how to translate "fall" to Chinese", https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english-chinese-simplified/fall-down https://bkrs.info/slovo.php?ch=%E6%91%94 https://bkrs.info/slovo.php?ch=%E8%90%BD https://bkrs.info/slovo.php?ch=%E6%8E%89

Answer (score 5, accepted):

摔: stress on the power, usually for human and animal stumbled, or things thrown by people.

落: a process, usually slow

掉: lost control, stress on the difference from the original position and new position,

So a plane landing successfully could be 落下 from sky, if the plane get some troubles and fall down, that could be 掉下 from sky.

A famous quote 天上掉下个林妹妹 from 红楼梦, 林妹妹 is a girl in case you don't know 红楼梦, she was a immortal live in heaven.

What if 天上**落**下个林妹妹, then 林妹妹 might use some magic to land on the earth. That is a common scene in a fantasy novel.

What if 天上**摔**下个林妹妹, a funny scene, imagine she walks on the heaven, then stumbled then hit the ground by head...

But 天上掉下个林妹妹, weird and unbelievable things happened, a beautiful girl fall from heaven and stand just in front of you.